# QGIS 2.2 Openlayers Plugin shift between shapefile and base layer for large format

Tags: qgis, printing, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am attempting to create a 24x36 map of New York City, and overlay it with a shapefile from City Planning. I'm using the Openlayers plugin, and I've tried all of the different types of base street map layers. I have been able to successfully convert the shapefile from a NAD 83 projection (EPSG 2263) to a WGS 84 projection (EPSG 3857), but I'm still suffering from some type of shift whenever I draw the map out on the print composer on a large scale piece of paper. The larger I try to print, the more dramatic the shift the misalignment.

[image: Aligned base layer and shapefile in browser]

[image: Misaligned layers in print composer]

Comment: Please try to add all layers in their nativ projection. Then enable the on-the-fly projection for the whole QGIS project to get the result in your desired projection. Cause this still the same problems?

Comment: Does the canvas change if you turn on `On-the-fly-reprojection`? Are you using OSM plugin or Openlayers plugin?

Comment: @Mapper I still have the same problem on the composer when I add the layers in the native projection and then enable on-the-fly

Comment: @AndreJoost I'm using the Openlayers plugin, and if I don't use OTF reprojection, and the original shapefile, it projects New York City to be roughly in the middle of the Atlantic ocean. Also, if you look at the print composer picture you might notice not only do boundaries not match up but neither does scale, and I'm not sure this can all be caused by projection issues.

Comment: This problem seems to occur every now and then: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827 and http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8824. Can you upload the shapefile somewhere?

Comment: @AndreJoost Here is the link to the source for my shapefiles http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/districts_download_metadata.shtml I'm working specifically with the City Council postredistricting file. They all use the same type of projection

Comment: @AndreJoost I realized I transformed the shapefile from the original CRS as well in an attempt to solve the problem. Here is a link to the transformed shapefiles in my Dropbox account. Upon further research I've found you're right and that this is a very common problem. I wish someone would develop an on the fly reprojection for printing. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5q4z97cor0rocv1/AAC9IdHF_8DPz2ej0GMVnz0Da

Answer (score 2):

According to some answers you need to size your map in composer to the same size as the page size. It works, but the only problem is that I loose my framing and coordinate indicators that is on the outside of map.
My personal bypass for this is the Georef Export Plugin. With that I first export the background image from google satelite  and load the saved image. The vectors are now neatly aligned and I can save it as pdf or image nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, your shapefiles work for me with and without `On-the-fly-reprojection`, exported as png and pdf:

[image]

Solid colour is the WGS84 file, and dotted the EPSG:3857 one. Without OTF, the WGS84 shifts to Nigeria, but the dotted remains:

[image]

Tested under Windows 7, also format A1 and Google background. Not sure what is different on your side. My Openlayers plugin is version 1.1.1, perhaps the update to 1.1.2 breaks it again?

Comment: I followed your steps and you are correct it works with A1. I then switched paper sizes in Print Composer to Arch D and A0 and ended up with the scale and misalignment issues. Perhaps whatever is used to reproject only works for printing small copies?

Comment: I made a mistake in my comment. I was able to get it to work with A4 not A1. I'm also on Win 7, Openlayers version 1.1.2 Is there a way for me to download and install the older version?

Comment: It should be in the standalone version. I now tested A0 format and got stuck with missing tiles, and QGIS crashing. This might be a memory issue.

Comment: I think I found a work around. It's about order of operations. If I select the paper size before I project the map it appears to work fine with the Arch D.

Comment: Well thats what I did without thinking about it.

Comment: Thanks I'm still running into problems on the exported image though. I'll let you know if I can pinpoint anything else.

Answer (score 0):

To follow this issue's development, please refer to [Bug report #5827 Printing issue](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5827)